# INT instruction handling

Tags: assembly, kernel, interrupt, opcode, isr

How to handle asm int XX instruction (software interrupt) from user mode in kernel mode driver

Can i:

1) add interrupt descriptor in IDT in x64 Windows (how about PatchGuard)?

2) add ISR through IoConnectInterruptEx routine?

Comment: User-mode code is not supposed to invoke interrupts in Windows.

Comment: It appears that the answer is no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table#Hooking